# Passing submatrices from master to slaves MPI

Tags: c, matrix, mpi

I'm trying to learn MPI and I've run into the following problem in one of my courses:

Consider a matrix A of dimensions n * n in which each element is an integer. Given 2 pair of indices (i1,j1) and (i2,j2) find the submatrix of such dimensions in matrix A for which it's elements sum is maximum.

I'd like some help on how to pass the submatrices to the processes. Should I calculate first how many submatrices (s) are in the matrix and send to each process N/s? How would I send the submatrices?

Some skeleton code I wrote:

```
#include<mpi.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<assert.h>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

#pragma comment (lib, "msmpi.lib")

enum CommunicationTag
{
    COMM_TAG_MASTER_SEND_TASK,
    COMM_TAG_MASTER_SEND_TERMINATE,
    COMM_TAG_SLAVE_SEND_RESULT,
};

void print_matrix(int mat[10][10], int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf("%d ", mat[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    //0. Init part, finding rank and number of processes

    int numprocs, rank, rc;
    rc = MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    if (rc != MPI_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Error starting MPI program. Terminating \n");
        MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rc);
    }

    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    printf("I'm rank %d. Num procs %d\n", rank, numprocs); fflush(stdout);


//1. different machine code
    if (rank == 0)
    {
        int n;
        scanf("%d", &n);

        int i1, i2, j1, j2;
        scanf("%d%d%d%d", &i1, &i2, &j1, &j2);

        int mat[10][10];

        //init data
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                mat[i][j] = (rand() % 100) - 50; //init random between -50 and 49
            }

        print_matrix(mat, n);

//here; how do I pass the submatrices to the processes?
        for (int i = 1; i < numprocs; i++) {
            MPI_Send(&i1, 1, MPI_INT, i, COMM_TAG_MASTER_SEND_TASK, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Send(&i2, 1, MPI_INT, i, COMM_TAG_MASTER_SEND_TASK, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Send(&j1, 1, MPI_INT, i, COMM_TAG_MASTER_SEND_TASK, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Send(&j2, 1, MPI_INT, i, COMM_TAG_MASTER_SEND_TASK, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

//here; how do I pass the submatrices to the processes?
        }
    }
    else {
        //if slave ...

    }
    system("Pause");
}
```

Comment: *"Given 2 pair of indices (i1,j1) and (i2,j2) find the submatrix of such dimensions in matrix A for which it's elements sum is maximum."* - I can't tell what's being asked for.  What are "such dimensions"?  Which dimensions?  What are the indices used for?  A small example would be very helpful.

Comment: So if I have a matrix A of dimensions 5x5 and two pair of indices (0,0) and (2,2) I would have a submatrix of dimension 3x3 (9 elements). In matrix A there would be 9 such submatrices.

Comment: There are potential for optimization prior to using MPI. For instance, the matrix of the partial sums on lines could be computed. Then, whatever the size of the submatrix is, the sum of a line of the submatrix is a difference between two terms. Then the same trick can be applied on columns: partial sums and difference. Finally, compute the max.

Comment: @N.Nae: So the only use of `i1, j1, i2, j2` is to compute `i2 - i1` and `j2 - j1` to get the dimensions?

Comment: @John Zwinck apparently, yes

Comment: This is really the sort of trivial simplification that you should work out on your own, and not include as an implicit part of the question.  I suggest you edit your question to say something more direct, such as `"Given a smaller dimension m (less than n), find the m x m submatrix in matrix A for which it's elements sum is maximum."`

Comment: not sure the submatrix is a square matrix. it could have size `p x q` with `p` and `q` less or equal than `n`.

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to stop thinking about how to use `MPI_Send()`.  The basic solution is to use `MPI_Bcast()` to transmit `A` to all the MPI processes.

Then divide the work up (no need to communicate for this, the same dividing logic can run in each process).  Compute the sums within each MPI process, and collect them in the main process using `MPI_Gather()`.  Choose the largest and you're done.

It really only requires two MPI operations: Bcast to distribute the input data to all processes, and Gather to centralize the results.

Note that all MPI processes need to execute the collective operations together in lockstep.  You only need `if (rank == 0)` to know which process should load the matrix and analyze the Gathered results.

Comment: with a bit of creativity, `MPI_Allgather()` can be replaced with `MPI_Reduce(..., MPI_MAXLOC, ...)`

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet: I agree, and I started to write that in my answer originally, but then decided it was added complexity for questionable benefit.  OP's just starting out, so I decided to KISS.